# Flutter V2: Dart analysis issue only in old project and some files

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

**I have tried many ways to solve it in the last 3 days, but nothing worked. Has anyone experienced it too?**

### Dart analysis issue

NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'type=' was called on null.

### Version information

- Dart SDK 2.12.2
- Dart IntelliJ 201.9335
- Android Studio 4.1.3
- Windows 10 10.0

### Details

NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'type=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: type=Instance of 'InterfaceTypeImpl'

```
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      Null.type= (dart:core/null.dart:1:1)
#2      ApplyResolutionVisitor.visitVariableDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/summary2/apply_resolution.dart:1327:13)
#3      VariableDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10555:49)
#4      NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#5      ApplyResolutionVisitor.visitVariableDeclarationList (package:analyzer/src/summary2/apply_resolution.dart:1345:20)
#6      VariableDeclarationListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10655:15)
#7      ApplyResolutionVisitor.visitTopLevelVariableDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/summary2/apply_resolution.dart:1231:20)
#8      TopLevelVariableDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:9909:15)
#9      LinkedContext.applyResolution (package:analyzer/src/summary2/bundle_reader.dart:512:11)
#10     LinkedUnitContext.applyResolution (package:analyzer/src/summary2/linked_unit_context.dart:93:25)
#11     PropertyInducingElementImpl.typeInternal (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6731:21)
#12     ElementTypeProvider.getFieldType (package:analyzer/src/generated/element_type_provider.dart:62:15)
#13     PropertyInducingElementImpl.type (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6724:52)
#14     PropertyAccessorElementImpl_ImplicitGetter.returnTypeInternal (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6579:47)
#15     ElementTypeProvider.getExecutableReturnType (package:analyzer/src/generated/element_type_provider.dart:49:15)
#16     PropertyAccessorElementImpl_ImplicitGetter.returnType (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6571:35)
#17     PropertyAccessorElementImpl_ImplicitGetter.typeInternal (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6596:19)
#18     ElementTypeProvider.getExecutableType (package:analyzer/src/generated/element_type_provider.dart:55:15)
#19     PropertyAccessorElementImpl_ImplicitGetter.type (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart:6582:56)
#20     SimpleIdentifierResolver._getTypeOfProperty (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/simple_identifier_resolver.dart:52:42)
#21     SimpleIdentifierResolver._resolve2 (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/simple_identifier_resolver.dart:257:20)
#22     SimpleIdentifierResolver.resolve (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/simple_identifier_resolver.dart:42:5)
#23     ResolverVisitor.visitSimpleIdentifier (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1863:51)
#24     SimpleIdentifierImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:8970:49)
#25     ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#26     ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#27     MethodInvocationResolver._resolveArguments (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:291:23)
#28     MethodInvocationResolver._resolveArguments_finishInference (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:295:5)
#29     MethodInvocationResolver._setDynamicResolution (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:782:5)
#30     MethodInvocationResolver._resolveReceiverType (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:675:5)
#31     MethodInvocationResolver._resolveReceiverNull (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:542:5)
#32     MethodInvocationResolver.resolve (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/method_invocation_resolver.dart:93:7)
#33     ElementResolver.visitMethodInvocation (package:analyzer/src/generated/element_resolver.dart:394:31)
#34     MethodInvocationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7186:49)
#35     ResolverVisitor.visitMethodInvocation (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1706:10)
#36     MethodInvocationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7186:49)
#37     AwaitExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:902:18)
#38     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#39     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitAwaitExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3137:51)
#40     ResolverVisitor.visitAwaitExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:944:11)
#41     AwaitExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:898:49)
#42     ExpressionStatementImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:3680:18)
#43     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#44     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitExpressionStatement (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3229:59)
#45     ExpressionStatementImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:3676:49)
#46     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#47     BlockImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1087:17)
#48     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#49     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3143:31)
#50     ScopedVisitor.visitBlock.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2480:13)
#51     ScopedVisitor._withDeclaredLocals (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:3076:8)
#52     ScopedVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2479:5)
#53     BlockImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1083:49)
#54     BlockFunctionBodyImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1042:13)
#55     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#56     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3146:55)
#57     ScopedVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2489:13)
#58     ResolverVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:957:13)
#59     BlockFunctionBodyImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1038:49)
#60     FunctionExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:5010:12)
#61     FunctionExpressionResolver.resolve (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/function_expression_resolver.dart:65:10)
#62     ResolverVisitor.visitFunctionExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1460:37)
#63     FunctionExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:5004:49)
#64     NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#65     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#66     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#67     ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#68     NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#69     ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#70     ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#71     ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#72     InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#73     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#74     ListLiteralImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6762:15)
#75     TypedLiteralResolver.resolveListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/typed_literal_resolver.dart:97:10)
#76     ResolverVisitor.visitListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1648:27)
#77     ListLiteralImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6757:49)
#78     NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#79     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#80     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#81     ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#82     NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#83     ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#84     ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#85     ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#86     InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#87     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#88     ListLiteralImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6762:15)
#89     TypedLiteralResolver.resolveListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/typed_literal_resolver.dart:97:10)
#90     ResolverVisitor.visitListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1648:27)
#91     ListLiteralImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6757:49)
#92     NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#93     ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#94     UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#95     ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#96     NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#97     ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#98     ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#99     ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#100    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#101    NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#102    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#103    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#104    ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#105    NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#106    ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#107    ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#108    ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#109    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#110    NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#111    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#112    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#113    ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#114    NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#115    ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#116    ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#117    ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#118    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#119    NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#120    ListLiteralImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6762:15)
#121    TypedLiteralResolver.resolveListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/typed_literal_resolver.dart:97:10)
#122    ResolverVisitor.visitListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1648:27)
#123    ListLiteralImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6757:49)
#124    NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#125    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#126    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#127    ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#128    NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#129    ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#130    ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#131    ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#132    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#133    NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#134    ListLiteralImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6762:15)
#135    TypedLiteralResolver.resolveListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/dart/resolver/typed_literal_resolver.dart:97:10)
#136    ResolverVisitor.visitListLiteral (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1648:27)
#137    ListLiteralImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6757:49)
#138    NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#139    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#140    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#141    ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#142    NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#143    ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#144    ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#145    ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#146    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#147    NamedExpressionImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7385:18)
#148    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#149    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3360:51)
#150    ResolverVisitor.visitNamedExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1744:11)
#151    NamedExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7380:49)
#152    ResolverVisitor.visitArgumentList (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:887:20)
#153    ArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:355:49)
#154    ResolverVisitor.visitInstanceCreationExpression (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1621:24)
#155    InstanceCreationExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6130:15)
#156    ReturnStatementImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:8621:18)
#157    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#158    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitReturnStatement (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3410:51)
#159    ResolverVisitor.visitReturnStatement (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1846:11)
#160    ReturnStatementImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:8617:49)
#161    NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#162    BlockImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1087:17)
#163    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#164    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3143:31)
#165    ScopedVisitor.visitBlock.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2480:13)
#166    ScopedVisitor._withDeclaredLocals (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:3076:8)
#167    ScopedVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2479:5)
#168    BlockImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1083:49)
#169    BlockFunctionBodyImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1042:13)
#170    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#171    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3146:55)
#172    ScopedVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2489:13)
#173    ResolverVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:957:13)
#174    BlockFunctionBodyImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1038:49)
#175    MethodDeclarationImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7042:12)
#176    ResolverVisitor.visitNode (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1750:10)
#177    UnifyingAstVisitor.visitMethodDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:3351:55)
#178    ScopedVisitor.visitMethodDeclarationInScope (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2926:11)
#179    ScopedVisitor.visitMethodDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2919:7)
#180    ResolverVisitor.visitMethodDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1666:11)
#181    MethodDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7033:49)
#182    NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
#183    ScopedVisitor.visitClassMembersInScope (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2550:18)
#184    ScopedVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:2531:7)
#185    ResolverVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1015:13)
#186    ClassDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1536:49)
#187    ResolverVisitor.visitCompilationUnit (package:analyzer/src/generated/resolver.dart:1091:23)
#188    CompilationUnitImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2134:49)
#189    LibraryAnalyzer._resolveFile (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:709:10)
#190    LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:139:7)
#191    _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#192    LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:138:11)
#193    LibraryAnalyzer.analyze (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:107:12)
#194    AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult2.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1319:63)
#195    PerformanceLog.run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/performance_logger.dart:32:15)
#196    AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult2 (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1296:20)
#197    AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1249:14)
#198    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
#199    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
#200    _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1788:10)
#201    runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1710:10)
#202    NullSafetyUnderstandingFlag.enableNullSafetyTypes (package:analyzer/dart/element/null_safety_understanding_flag.dart:42:12)
#203    AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1248:40)
#204    AnalysisDriver._computeIndex (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1386:37)
#205    AnalysisDriver.performWork (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:995:39)
#206    AnalysisDriverScheduler._run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:2018:24)
<asynchronous suspension>

#0      Driver._captureExceptions.errorFunction (package:analysis_server/src/server/driver.dart:480:7)
#1      _CustomZone.handleUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1241:19)
#2      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1164:7)
#3      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
#4      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#5      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#6      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:120:13)
#7      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:402:11)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

### Debug log

```
1617529296421 => {"id":"1198","method":"analysis.updateContent","params":{"files":{"C:\\Users\\krish\\AndroidStudioProjects\\smart_vendor\\lib\\screens\\detail_order_screen.dart":{"type":"add","conten...
1617529296421 <= {"id":"1198","result":{}}
1617529296421 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":true}}}
1617529296452 => {"id":"1199","method":"edit.getAssists","params":{"file":"C:\\Users\\krish\\AndroidStudioProjects\\smart_vendor\\lib\\screens\\detail_order_screen.dart","offset":124,"length":0},"clie...
1617529296608 <= {"id":"1199","result":{"assists":[]}}
1617529296608 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":982,"uri":"package:smart_vendor/screens/screens.dart","items":[{"label":"IllustrationPage","declaringLib...
1617529296608 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":false}}}
1617529297046 => {"id":"1200","method":"analysis.updateContent","params":{"files":{"C:\\Users\\krish\\AndroidStudioProjects\\smart_vendor\\lib\\screens\\detail_order_screen.dart":{"type":"add","conten...
1617529297046 <= {"id":"1200","result":{}}
1617529297046 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":true}}}
1617529297077 => {"id":"1201","method":"edit.getAssists","params":{"file":"C:\\Users\\krish\\AndroidStudioProjects\\smart_vendor\\lib\\screens\\detail_order_screen.dart","offset":123,"length":0},"clie...
1617529297216 <= {"id":"1201","result":{"assists":[]}}
1617529297232 <= {"event":"completion.availableSuggestions","params":{"changedLibraries":[{"id":982,"uri":"package:smart_vendor/screens/screens.dart","items":[{"label":"IllustrationPage","declaringLib...
1617529297232 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":false}}}
1617529299111 => {"id":"1202","method":"edit.getAssists","params":{"file":"C:\\Users\\krish\\AndroidStudioProjects\\smart_vendor\\lib\\screens\\detail_order_screen.dart","offset":261,"length":8},"clie...
1617529299173 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":true}}}
1617529299173 <= {"id":"1202","result":{"assists":[]}}
1617529299173 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":false}}}
1617529300705 => {"id":"1203","method":"analysis.setPriorityFiles","params":{"files":["C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart"]},"clientRequestTime":1617529300...
1617529300705 => {"id":"1204","method":"analysis.setSubscriptions","params":{"subscriptions":{"OVERRIDES":["C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart"],"CLOSING_L...
1617529300705 <= {"id":"1203"}
1617529300705 <= {"id":"1204"}
1617529300830 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":true}}}
1617529300845 <= {"event":"analysis.highlights","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","regions":[{"type":"DIRECTIVE","offset":169,"length":...
1617529300861 <= {"event":"analysis.navigation","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","regions":[{"offset":176,"length":12,"targets":[0]},{...
1617529300861 <= {"event":"analysis.closingLabels","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","labels":[{"offset":9145,"length":486,"label":"Flu...
1617529300876 <= {"event":"analysis.outline","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","kind":"LIBRARY","outline":{"element":{"kind":"COMPILATI...
1617529300876 <= {"event":"analysis.overrides","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","overrides":[{"offset":2033,"length":8,"superclassMemb...
1617529300892 <= {"event":"flutter.outline","params":{"file":"C:\\Developments\\flutter\\packages\\flutter\\lib\\src\\widgets\\framework.dart","outline":{"kind":"DART_ELEMENT","offset":0,"length":2660...
1617529300892 <= {"event":"server.status","params":{"analysis":{"isAnalyzing":false}}}
```

**This is one of some files that caused this exception:**

```
library screens;

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smart_vendor/lang/lang.dart';
import 'package:smart_vendor/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:smart_vendor/models/models.dart';
import 'package:smart_vendor/shared/shared.dart';
import 'package:smart_vendor/widgets/widgets.dart';

part 'address_page.dart';
part 'general_page.dart';
part 'sign_in_page.dart';
part 'sign_up_page.dart';
part 'sign_up_agent_page.dart';
part 'sign_up_personal_page.dart';
part 'sign_up_business_page.dart';
part 'main_page.dart';
part 'profile_page.dart';
part 'history_page.dart';
part 'illustration_page.dart';
part 'filter_page.dart';
part 'success_page.dart';
part 'success_sign_up_page.dart';
part 'take_order_confirmation_page.dart';
part 'detail_order_screen.dart';
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide code where this exception is appeared

Comment: Sure, i have edited the post

Comment: Thank you. After having analysed your data, I believe that this error occurs after upgrading your flutter and dart sdks.


I would recommend updating your project to null-safety and see if errors are disappeared.

If it does not, you should debug your code, and find bug.

P.s. Your provided data is not enough to find where the error is.